# jQuery usage of $.contains() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript in general and i'm trying to make an image appear and disappear on click in a table using the [`$.contains(container,contained)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/#jQuery-contains-container-contained) method on a td element, but it doesn't seem to work properly. This is the example code.

```js
var td = document.getElementById('1');

td.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'; //sample image

  if ($.contains(td, img)) {
    td.removeChild(img);
  } else {
    td.appendChild(img);
  }

}, false);
```

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: code was full of error and/or trials. Now i cleaned it up.

Comment: 1. Do not start IDs with a number. 2 Why not use jQuery to get the object and assign the event handler? 3. I would not thing the img in the table is the same object you just created

Comment: `if($('#1').find('img').length) { // condition }`, or if you only want a direct descendant: `if ($('#1').find('> img').length) { // condition }`.

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen? You append and immediately remove the element, currently.

Comment: Edited. I wrote it right on the real page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery implementation of your code.
What is the actual thing you want to achieve? the test is never true if you add a new image object

Perhaps you want to know if there is an image in the cell?

```js
var $td = $('#cell_1');

$td.on('click', function() {

  var $img = $("<img/>", {
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text='+new Date().getTime()
  }); //sample image

  var $images = $td.find("img");
  if ($images.length>0) { 
    $images.remove(); 
  } else {
    $td.append($img);
  }

});
```

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Plain JS:

```js
var td = document.getElementById('cell_1');

td.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src= 'https://via.placeholder.com/99x99?text='+new Date().getTime(); 

  var images = td.querySelectorAll("img");
  if (images.length>0) { 
    td.innerHTML=""; // or loop over child elements
  } else {
    td.appendChild(img);
  }

},false);
```

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding:0;
  
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td id="cell_1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I'm sorry for my wrong code, it was just a fast copy of the original one with trials. Is there anyway of writing this code in plain javascript?

Comment: I've implemented this in jquery, it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove:

```
td.appendChild(img);
```

after img declaration.

Your code create, appends than always removes the image.

As it is, `if ($.contains(td, img)){...}` always return true.

Comment: Was a part of a trial i did. I wrote this question too fast. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `contains()`, which is really good for text elements, you should instead try:

```
if($('#1').find('img').length) { 
    // condition
}
```

or if you want a direct descendant of the parent element:

```
if ($('#1').find('> img').length) {
    // condition
}
```

Here's a version that doesn't use the id selector, but instead checks if the clicked element's direct descendant contains an image:

```
if($(this).find('> img').length) {
    // condition
}
```

Comment: How do i remove the image? If the `$(this).find('> img').length` condition is true i want to remove the image but `td.removeChild(img);` does not work. Any workaround using only js?

Comment: Erhm, short on time as of right now, but try `$(this).find('> img').hide();` or assign an id to the specific element (image in this case) `$('#idName').hide();`. then you can do `.show();` whenever you want to show it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if an element is a descendant of another.

```
$.contains( document.documentElement, document.body ); // true
$.contains( document.body, document.documentElement ); // false
```

We can also use .contains to select an element which contains is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
Who is Batman?
</body>
</html>
```

This will select the following tags:

```
 <p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
 <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```